# How to stop something from printing after its work is done?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, my task was to write a code for a pangram checker and then display the missing alphabets. This is what I have written so far:-

```
MAX_CHAR = 26

# Returns characters that needs
# to be added to make str
def ispanagram(Str):
    # A boolean array to store characters
    # present in string.
    present = [False for i in range(MAX_CHAR)]

    # Traverse string and mark characters
    # present in string.
    for i in range(len(Str)):
        if (Str[i] >= 'a' and Str[i] <= 'z'):
            present[ord(Str[i]) - ord('a')] = True
        elif (Str[i] >= 'A' and Str[i] <= 'Z'):
            present[ord(Str[i]) - ord('A')] = True

    # Store missing characters in alphabetic
    # order.
    res = ""

    for i in range(MAX_CHAR):
        if (present[i] == False):
            res += chr(i + ord('a')) + ", "

    return res

def main():
    Str = input()
    fg = ispanagram(Str)
    if not fg:
        print("Yes, the string is a pangram.")
    else:
        print("No, the string is NOT a pangram. Missing letter(s) is(are) " + str(fg))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Call the main function
    main()
```

Results:

```
inp = The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
Out = Yes, the string is a pangram.
inp = Hi, I am xyz
Out = No, the string is NOT a pangram. Missing letter(s) is(are) b, c, d, e, f, g, j, k, l, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w,
```

This code is working fine but an extra comma is being printed after the last alphabet is printed. How do I stop it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `.join()`

```
res=[chr(i + ord('a')) for i in range(MAX_CHAR) if present[i]==False]
return ', '.join(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a list and join 'em:

```
# Use a list
res = []

for i in range(MAX_CHAR):
    if (present[i] == False):
        res.append(chr(i + ord('a')))

# Join 'em
return ', '.join(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution - 1**

Instead of concatenating to a string, you can use a list for `res` to store the characters.

Then to display them with commas, you can do - `', '.join(res)`. *This will avoid printing that trailing comma.*

```
res = []

    for i in range(MAX_CHAR):
        if (present[i] == False):
            res.append(chr(i + ord('a')))
    
    return ', '.join(res)



def main():
    Str = input()
    fg = ispanagram(Str)
    if not fg:
        print("Yes, the string is a pangram.")
    else:
        print("No, the string is NOT a pangram. Missing letter(s) is(are) " + fg)
```

**Solution - 2**

Use `rstrip(', ')` to strip off that trailing comma from `res`.

```
res = ""

    for i in range(MAX_CHAR):
        if (present[i] == False):
            res += chr(i + ord('a')) + ", "

    return res.rstrip(', ')
```